# jquery не видит checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

Здравствуйте! Имеется такая форма:

```
<form name="formSocial" class="formSocial">
        <div class="social col-md-12"><!-- Социальные сети-->
            <label class="form-group col-md-8">Социальные сети</label>

            <div class="col-md-12" style="margin-top: 50px">
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <label>Вконтакте:</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <input class="form-control" name="1" type="text" placeholder="ссылка">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <label>Выкл/Вкл</label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="1">
                </div>
            </div>
               ....
        </div>
```

И скрипт который достает данные из этой формы:

```
$('.saveSocial').on('click', function(){
    var arr = $(".formSocial").serializeAnotherArray();
    $.fn.serializeAnotherArray = function(){
      var arr = $(this).serializeArray(),b=[],c=[];
      $.each(arr,function(){
      c.push(this.name.replace('[]',''),this.value);
      if(c.length==4){
          b.push(c);
          c = [];
       }
      });
        return b;
    }

    console.log(arr);

    });
```

В результате хочу получить такой массив:

```
(4) ["1", "one", "1", "on"]

(4) ["2", "two", "2", "on"]
           ...
```

Если чекбокс не выбран метод serializeAnotherArray не видит его и пропускает. Получается массив типа такого:

```
["1", "one", "2", "two", "3", ""]
```

Читал что `jquery` видит только отмеченные чекбоксы. Можно этого как-то избежать и если чекбокс не выбран сделать его по умолчанию `off`. Или как-то по другому решить этот вопрос?

Comment: jquery абсолютно все равно отмечены ли чекбоксы или нет. Попробуйте для проверки пройтись по ним селектором: $(input[type="checkbox"]) и посмотрите сколько элементов он найдет.

Comment: неотмеченый чекбокс браузер щитает чем-то типа "отсутствие информации" поэтому надо либо проверять отсутствие/наличие нужного значения либо сделать сериализацию вручную.

Comment: @Vitalii, если так проверять, то все чекбоксы выделяются как отмеченные хотя на самом деле нет

Comment: @Rostyslav Kuzmovych, можете по подробнее как это можно реализовать?

Comment: @r.mcreal это просто селектор для поиска чекбоксов. А дальше вы уже проверяете то, что вам надо.

Comment: @Vitalii, подскажите пожалуйста как мне теперь определить какой чекбокс отмечен, и как все это засунуть в массив для отправки?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ак приятно видеть свой код на стаке)

Если правильно понял, тебе это нужно:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.saveSocial').on('click', function(e){
        var arr = $(".formSocial").serializeAnotherArray();
        console.log(arr);
    });
});

$.fn.serializeAnotherArray = function(){
    var a = {};
    $.each($(this).find('[name]'),function(){
        var s = $(this),name = s.attr('name');
        if(typeof a[name] == 'undefined') a[name] = [];
        a[name].push(name,s.is(':checkbox')?(s.is(':checked')?'on':'off'):s.val());
    });
    return Object.values(a);
}
```

Comment: ваш код выручал много раз, как и Вы сами) Огромное спасибо!

Comment: Извините, возник один вопрос. Как сделать так чтобы скрипт брал значение инпутов только внутри формы `.formSocial`? А то сейчас получается так что он берет значения из всех инпутов на странице. P.S. вроде вы это здесь прописали `var arr = $(".formSocial").serializeAnotherArray();` но почему то не работает(

Comment: посмотри, может <form> не закрыт в **serializeAnotherArray** приходит только один элемент это **.formSocial**